# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm not sure how to resolve this type script error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'OkPacket | RowDataPacket[] | ResultSetHeader[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket[] | ProcedureCallPacket'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'OkPacket | RowDataPacket[] | ResultSetHeader[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket[] | ProcedureCallPacket'.
```

I'm using the fastify example here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mysql

Here is the full code on the github

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('@fastify/mysql'), {
  promise: true,
  connectionString: 'mysql://root@localhost/mysql'
})

fastify.get('/user/:id', async (req, reply) => {
  const connection = await fastify.mysql.getConnection()
  const [rows, fields] = await connection.query(
    'SELECT id, username, hash, salt FROM users WHERE id=?', [req.params.id],
  )
  connection.release()
  return rows[0]
})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
})
```

How do I create an appropriate interface to stop this error?

**Update:** I ended up creating a single interface and then did the following to fix it:

```
declare interface RowDataPacket {
  constructor: {
    name: 'RowDataPacket';
  };
  [column: string]: any;
  [column: number]: any;
}
```

then did:

...

```
  connection.release()
  let row = rows as RowDataPacket
  return row[0]
```

...

Comment: Code you have added is javascript, not typescript, also when do you get this error? include the code you have to the question.